# Github Action docker/build-push-action@v4 to ECR returns untagged images

Tags: docker, github-actions, amazon-ecr

I have a github build that pushes images to ECR, but when they get there, they show up as untagged / no way i can see to tell image / platform etc is created. Is this a bug or a mistake my end?

GHA:

```
name: push
on: [workflow_dispatch]
env:
  ECR_REPOSITORY: gha
jobs:
  build-image:
    name: Build Images
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
 
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_MGMT_ECR_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_MGMT_ECR_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-west-2

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
        
      - name: Set up docker buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
 
      - name: Docker meta
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: |
            ${{ env.ECR_REGISTRY }}/${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
          tags: |
            type=semver,pattern={{version}},value=1.0.0
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
      
      - name: Docker build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
```

And in ECR i then see:

[image]

Comment: Any fix you got ?

Answer (score 4):

Just add `provenance: false` in docker/build-push-action@v4

Comment: Hi, yes ive tried adding below is my current config and still returns a `image index` and 2 images that are untagged (guessing this is 1 for amd and 1 for arm) it would just be nice to see them tagged 


```
      - name: Docker build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
          provenance: false
          sbom: false
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use the metadata action. But here is a sample working with ECR:

```
    steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Set up Docker Buildx
    uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

  - name: Cache Docker layers
    uses: actions/cache@v2
    with:
      path: /tmp/.buildx-cache
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-buildx-${{ github.sha }}
      restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.os }}-buildx-

  - name: Configure AWS credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1-node16
    with:
      role-to-assume: ${{ env.ROLE_TO_ASSUME }}
      role-session-name: github-actions-${{ env.APP_NAME }}
      aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

  - name: Login to Amazon ECR
    id: login-ecr
    uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

  - name: Set short sha
    id: sha_short
    run: echo "sha_short=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  - name: Build and push
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
    with:
      context: .
      file: ./Dockerfile
      push: true
      tags: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}/${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:${{ steps.sha_short.outputs.sha_short }}
      cache-from: type=local,src=/tmp/.buildx-cache
      cache-to: type=local,dest=/tmp/.buildx-cache
      provenance: false
```

Comment: If you add platform and generate multiple images does it still tag everything?

Comment: Yes, you can create multiple tags. For ECR, I found the "provenance" is required because ECR limitation.

Comment: problems not mulitple tags, its that its showing images as untagged via the GUI. But this looks to be by design at present and not a user error (Which is what i first thought)

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is 11 months old but thanks to comparing Scoup's post with mine. I seen that OP and I shared similar workflows and the only thing different between mine and Scoup's was the addition of the Setup QEMU action.

```
        name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3
```

Turns out this workflow (https://github.com/docker/setup-qemu-action) is meant to add "emulation support with QEMU to be able to build against more platforms." - https://github.com/docker/build-push-action?tab=readme-ov-file

And after my own testing, I found that removing this action deploys my images to ECR without the image index and the seemingly empty images that were actually manifest files for QEMU.
[image]

I'm unsure if it will affect the deployment but I can follow up on the thread later.

- Update, the original deployed image is working as intended so removing the QEMU fixed my issues with the Image Index and Qemu manifest image

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, and would be reasonable to say the ECR UI is showing more data than is needed. In short, you should just ignore it. There's even a [roadmap issue](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1596) requesting improvements to the UI that you can up vote.

Multi-platform images will have a manifest list, or index, that is tagged. That manifest contains a descriptor to each platform specific manifest, which will technically be an untagged manifest, but reachable by the tag on the index. And with recent versions of docker, SLSA build provenance is also included as an artifact in that same index, wrapped in the same image manifest structure.

To inspect these images, you can use [`docker buildx imagetools inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/buildx/imagetools/inspect/) (or similar tools like Google's crane, RedHat's skopeo, or my own regctl). From there you can see that the tagged index has descriptors pointing to those other untagged digests, and details about each of the entries (which platform or which image the provenance is associated with).